# Инструменты для тестирования на C и C++

Tags: юнит-тесты

Для JavaScript есть удобные тулзы дя тестирования типа Jasmine и Mocha. Тесты запускаются всего одной командой в консоли. Есть ли что-то похожее для C и C++, но не тяжеловесная унылая гадость для продакшена типа GoogleMock? Мне надо просто протестировать длиинную арифметику и работу с низкоуровневыми численными типами. Тащить для этого за собой 10мб библиотеки для тестирования я не хочу.

Answer (score 0):

Использую google test для тестирования в паре с https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt для mock-объектов.